# Swift - return itself property on getter and set itself on setter

Tags: swift, getter-setter

Is anyway to return itself property in the getter and set itself on the setter? Because I just want to print a log inside the getter and the setter and thats it.

For example I trying to do something like this:

```
private(set) var internetConnectionAvailable: Bool {
    get {
        logger.debug("verifying internet connection")
        // here return itself property
    }
    set {
        logger.debug("changing internet connection")
        // here set itself
    }
}
```

If I return `self.internetConnectionAvailable` on the getter I get:

> Linker command failed with exit code 1

when I try to compile the project.

I'm trying to do that because I don't want to create an extra private property to store the get and the set. I'm looking if there are something different to achieve that.

Comment: Sounds like a linker issue. Can you add the whole error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT: I note that you said you don't want to create an extra private property. Then sorry. No. Not unless you make this an `NSManagedObject` subclass (and hook into the `willAccessValueForKey` system), or otherwise hook into the ObjC runtime on an `NSObject` (you could swizzle your own getter for instance to add logging; don't laugh, I've done that before). But all of these approaches are insane in Swift (and insane in ObjC; I only used them for debugging). Just make the backing variable.**

If you only wanted to log the setter, then this would be straightforward: use `willSet` rather than `set`. But logging the getter requires implementing it all by hand. You do that with a private backing variable.

```
private var _internetConnectionAvailable: Bool
private(set) var internetConnectionAvailable: {
    get {
        logger.debug("verifying internet connection")
        return _internetConnectionAvailable
    }
    set {
        logger.debug("changing internet connection")
        _internetConnectionAvailable = newValue
    }
}
```

Once you define `get` yourself, you've said you don't want the default handling, which means you get no automatic backing variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid Swift without a backing property:

```
private(set) var internetConnectionAvailable: Bool {
    get {
        print("verifying internet connection")
        // here return itself property
        return false
    }
    set {
        print("changing internet connection")
        // here set itself
    }
}
```

Just need to specify a type, and return `false` from the `get`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the Bool type in the question.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how this would work. Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop of getting/setting?

Comment: Nope, when you set the property, nothing happens (except for your log), and when you get the property, `false` is always returned (and your other log is printed).